# Restrict the size of a layout width in a chat app

Tags: java, android

The app I am building requires a simple chat module. I've got everything to work except restricting the width of each chat bubble that appears in the chat screen which is a Recyclerview.

The design logic is that if the width taken up by the chat bubble is greater than or equal to 70% of the screen width then the view will be restricted to 70% of the width, otherwise it will take up as much width as needed. You can observe how the chat bubble width are [restricted in this image](https://s.muz.li/go?link=https://www.uplabs.com/posts/social-group-chat-app-react-native). (It's a lot easier in iOS where the the UI is completely programmatically built.)

So what I did was define the initial case in the XML for a left:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/chat_message"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nexabold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_chat_left"
        android:padding="8dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And then for the right:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/chat_message"
        android:textColor="@color/fullWhite"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nexabold"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_chat_right"
        android:padding="8dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Finally, in my bind view holder method in the adapter for the Recyclerview I do the following. My thinking is that I leave the start (outgoing msg) /end (incoming msg) constraints open in the XML and populate the textview. If the textviews is more than 70% then restrict the width. This, however, isn't working and I am not sure why. I end up with the text spilling outside of the screen regardless.[image]

```
   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessagesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tvMessage.setText(messagesArray.get(position).getBody());

        Context context = holder.tvMessage.getContext();
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = holder.tvMessage.getLayoutParams();
        if (layoutParams.width >= screenWidth * 0.7) {
            holder.tvMessage.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int) (screenWidth * 0.7), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use LinearLayout with horizontal orientation for your chat message, then set weightsum of LinearLayout to 1 and set width of text view which displays chat message to 0dp and set its weight to 0.7 so that it will take 0.7 of 1.

Comment: That does not work. I get the same affect as leaving it in Constraint Layout and programmatically forcing the text view to take up 70% of the total window.